# JSP Display User Details not working at all

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

```
        <!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Mail Registration</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="newcss.css">
        <link rel="text/javascript" href="validateForm.js">

    </head>
    <body>


        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h1>Online Book Store Mailing Registration</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <div id ="leftSide">
                    <p>Welcome to the Online Book Store Registration.
                    In order to join our mailing list you must complete the form. Then press the Submit button.</p>

                </div>
                <div id="rightSide">
                <h2>Thanks for joining our email list</h2>
                <h3>Here is the information that you entered:</h3>
                 <%@ page import="user.User" %>
                <% User user = (User) request.getAttribute("User");%>

        <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th align="right">First Name:</th>
                <th>${user.getFirstName}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="right">Last Name:</th>
                <th>${user.getLastName}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="right">Town:</th>
                <th>${user.getTown}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="right">Country:</th>
                <th>${user.getCountry}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="right">Email Address:</th>
                <th>${user.getEmailAddress}</th>
            </tr>
        </table>

                </form>
                <br />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <h2>xxx</h2>



         </div>
         </div>
        </body>
       </html>
```

This is my first time working with JSP, I have to display user details that have been added to database. I have been looking for some time now at other questions asked here about displaying details and I have not found an answer yet.
I have java class called User.java in user Package. 
If anyone could point me where I went wrong I would be thankful.

I have this in my servlet

```
 String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
String town = request.getParameter("town");
String country = request.getParameter("country");
String emailAddress = request.getParameter("emailAddress");

// create the User object
User User = new User();
User.setFirstName(firstName);
User.setLastName(lastName);
User.setTown(town);
User.setCountry(country);
User.setEmailAddress(emailAddress);   
MailDB.insert(User);
request.setAttribute("User", User);
String url = "/return_user_details.jsp";
RequestDispatcher dispatcher =     getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your User class is like this :

```
Class User {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String country;
        .
        .
        .
   /*generating getters & setters*/
   public String getFirstName(){
       return firstName;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String firstName){
       this.firstName = firstName;
   }

}
```

So the problem you're having is here `${user.getFirstName}` this will never work unless your attribute is named `getFirstName` which I don't think you did so to solve this issue you simply have to :

**replace**
`${user.getFirstName}` with `${user.firstName}` , generally use the attribute name and not the getters and setters methods name.

Comment: Yes, my User class is identical. I already tried `${user.firstName}` and return_user_details.jsp is still not displaying the results.

Comment: before setting the User object in the request with `request.setAttribute("User", User);` try to make a `System.out.println(User.toString())` to check if really the User object is fullfilled & it's not null !!

Comment: I am getting `Info:   user.User@7d1ccecd` 
So I decided to use Debugger (I am using netbeans) and the User object is filled with data I have input.

Comment: have you tried to display it by using scriplets instead of EL tags ??

Comment: I have not, thanks for the suggestion .Using the EL tags was the only way I was shown. I will read about scriplets, try them and get back here if it still won't work.

Comment: Scriplets is quite simple just replace the `${user.firstName}` with `<=user.getFirstName()>` and see the result if it's okay so it means that you are not loading the `JSTL` in your `return_user_details.jsp` which will cause the problem surely

Comment: Yeah, that is working. I should add the JSTL now. Thanks for the help